# Как добавить файл с зависимостями в репозиторий github командой, при этом не добавляя его в отслеживание git add?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

Нужно добавить файл с либами, req.json один раз на гитхаб в репозиторий. Как это сделать командой в Git'e? Мне не нужно его комитить, т.е каждый раз отслеживать его изменения, этот файлик у меня в .gitignore, но мне нужно единоразово добавить его в репозиторий на github

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно воспользоваться командной строкой Git и запушить файл в удаленный репозиторий.
   То есть последовательно выполнить
   git add ...
   git commit ...
   git push ...
2. Также в UI интерфейсе github, у созданного вами проекта, есть функция подгрузки файлов.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Невозможно «добавить в репозиторий», но «не коммитить», потому что файл добавляется в репозиторй командой commit, а в удалённый еще и последующей push.

.gitignore влияет только на неотслеживаемые файлы, на такие команды как git status и git add *

Чтоб файл появился в репозитории вам придётся его добавить, закоммитить и запушить также как и любые другие.

После помещения в репозиторий можно поставить флаг assume-unchanged, говорящий git'у, что дальнейшие локальные изменения можно игнорировать. Делается это командой `git update-index --assume-unchanged <файл>`.

Но делать это нужно в каждой локальной копии, и он сбрасывается при некоторых командах, таких как reset.